# Get file type with Apache FTPClient

Tags: java, ftp-client

We are having issues where sometimes no error is thrown when a file is partially uploaded over FTP. For example, if we transfer an image only half of it will be transferred and then it will return without any error. I wanted to add a check so that after the file is transferred I will get the size of the file in the server and check if the size match.

This is fine when we are using binary transfer mode but when we use the ASCII transfer mode the size usually doesn't match even when the complete file is transferred. To avoid false negatives I wanted to add this check only when the transfer mode is `BINARY`

How can we get the file type with java Apache FTPClient, I could find methods only to set the file type but none to get the file type.

As a workaround I can execute the `TYPE` command and parse the response, I wanted to know if there is an option in the client so that I don't have to maintain additional code.--> this doesn't work either, executing the `TYPE` command I get a replay saying `501 Missing required argument`.

Edit: The code is part of our product and I can't force the users to always use binary mode.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and say that the reason the file size differs when TEXT is a result of en/decoding problem. I'd use BINARY all the time and make sure you read it with the correct encoding

Comment: The problem the code is shipped as part of our product and we have no control over the type they use, we can't always force them to use Binary.

Comment: I'm not convinced that your problem is as you stated. You are dealing with a technology (though superseded [since it's inherently insecure] by SFtp -  which is what you should be using) is *specifically designed* to transfer files correctly. Handwaving about the 'size' of the files is redundant. It's like IDing someone by fingerprint scanning then saying "Hang on, this is not quite right. I'd better check his shoe size just to make sure"

Comment: I do understand the limitations of the FTP and its pitfalls, But I don't control all the external applications our tool talks to and there are many using FTP and I have to support it. I have no other way.

Comment: OK, so if a file is sent to an ftp server and arrives incomplete (without any intervening processing) then you need to ascertain what's wrong with the server. Not a Java issue though